# How to open Facebook and Twitter share buttons when clicking on it in a WKWebView(swift 3)?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, swift3, wkwebview

I am actually using a WKWebView in my IOS application. The url loaded successfully but when clicking on the Facebook and Twitter share buttons nothing happens. How can I solve this issue?

Here is the following code:

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil

    var webView = WKWebView()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.examplepage.com")!
        webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: url as URL) as URLRequest)
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```